# How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript with repeating values

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-comparison

How can I check to see if one array is contained in another and return the missing values? I have found ways to do this [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript) but none account for repeating values in the arrays. For example, I am trying to do something like this:

```
getDiff([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) --> []

getDiff([1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) --> [2]

getDiff(["A", "B", "C"], ["B", "B", "A", "C"]) --> []

getDiff(["B", "B", "B"], [3, 2, 1]) --> ["B", "B", "B"]
```

Comment: If you post what you have tried, someone can more readily help you fix/finish it.

Comment: If the order of the result doesn't matter, this would be simplified by sorting the two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```js
function getRepeatingDiff(source, diffed) {
  const diffedCounter = diffed.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  const diff = source.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return diffedCounter[el]-- > 0 ? acc : [ ...acc, el ];
  }, []);
  
  return diff;
}

console.log( getRepeatingDiff([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff([1, 3, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff(["A", "B", "C"], ["B", "B", "A", "C"]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff(["B", "B", "B"], [3, 2, 1]) );
```

Essentially, it's a two-step process: calculate the number of items in `diffed` array, then go through `source` array one more time - and add a new item into `diff` resulting array for each copy missing in `diffedCounter`. This particular implementation has one deficiency though: as it uses Object to collect the counts, it doesn't differentiate between `3` as number and `'3'` as a string when counting elements.

This might be fixed in two different ways: either switch to Map (but that'll make code more complicated, as there's no such things as decrementing for map values) - or just use type prefixes when creating a counter keys. Here's the approach based on former:

```js
function getRepeatingDiff(source, diffed) {
  const diffedCounter = diffed.reduce((map, el) => {
    const prev = map.get(el);
    return map.set(el, (prev || 0 ) + 1);
  }, new Map());
  
  const diff = source.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const remainingCount = diffedCounter.get(el);
    if (remainingCount) diffedCounter.set(el, remainingCount - 1);
    return remainingCount ? acc : [ ...acc, el ];
  }, []);
  
  return diff;
}

console.log( getRepeatingDiff([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff([1, 3, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff(["A", "B", "C"], ["B", "B", "A", "C"]) );
console.log( getRepeatingDiff(["B", "B", "B"], [3, 2, 1]) );
```

Comment: I realized it's way too inefficient to go through the source array twice, so updated my answer. It still doesn't differentiate between numbers and strings though.

Comment: perhaps you can use a Map instead of an object